# Cannot access the server anymore

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-access, nic

I was accessing the Windows Server 2012 R2 Remotely which is NIC 1 (192.168.1.x), this server had NIC 1, then NIC 2 (192.168.4.x) which was disconnected.

I read somewhere that I can't let NIC 2 connect with NIC 1, so I went to network-sharing center-Adapters- NIC 2- Properties- Sharing tab, and I shared NIC 2 with NIC 1.

The Server went down NIC 1 ( 192.168.1.x) and I cannot access it remotely anymore

What should I do to resolve this and gain access again?

Comment: Log in at the local console and revert your changes.

Comment: Having a management port configured if you can't go local ?